# FTP Programming in PHP

Tags: php

FTP Connection Established but file was not moving

Below Code we tried to transfer the file Via FTP.

```
<?php
$server = "115.248.19.68";
$ftp_user_name = "Test"; // Username
$ftp_user_pass = "test@123"; // Password

$mode="FTP_BINARY";

$connection = ftp_connect($server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

echo "Connection Established";

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); exit; }

$dst = 'C:\FTP\A/'; 

$file = fopen("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\dt.txt", "r+") or exit("Unable to 
open file!");

$line = fgets($file);

$date1 = new DateTime($line);

$flg=0;
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = 
glob("C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\FTP/*.*"))), SORT_DESC, $files);


foreach($files as $filename)
{
$date2 = new DateTime(date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename)));
if($date1 < $date2) {



$p=pathinfo($filename);
$file_to_go =$dst.$p['filename'].".".$p['extension'];

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $file_to_go, $filename, FTP_BINARY);
} else {
break;
}
} 
ftp_close($connection);   
file_put_contents("C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\test\\dt.txt", "");
fwrite($file,date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($files[0])));
?>
```

We have the dt.txt file, it will store the Last sent file Datetime and next time it will transfer from the new update d timestamp.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file reveal what the actual issue is?

Comment: there is no error showing while running this code. it shows simply connection Established but files not transfered from the folder.

Comment: do you see anything in the `dt.txt`?

Comment: Yes, at end we will see the Date and Time of the Last file.

Comment: @VengatesanM I think you miss understood my question. Usually php scripts are executed inside the environment of a http server. That server always does write an error log file, unless you specifically disabled that feature (which hardly makes any sense). Errors, warnings and notices raised by the php engine are typically logged into that error log file. That has nothing to do with a log file you yourself specifically create and fill. In general : you _can not_ program in php in a web environment without monitoring that error log file.